# Most appropriate Tag to Mark a Section of HTML Text to Minipulate with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to mark a section of text to dynamically edit with JavaScript. 
After skimming through the [List of Inline Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements), I decided to use [`<a>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), which seems like a no-brainer choice.

```js
function updatePrice() {
  var current = Number($(".price").text());
  $(".price").text(1 + current);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>This item is $<a class="price">1</a></p>
<button onClick = "updatePrice();">One Up!</button>
```

I played around with [`<var>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/var) as well, but it seems to be a wrong usage for the tag - it's supposed to be used for the **name of the variable**
, not the variable itself.

While `<a>` seems to be the best choice, it seems like a wrong usage for the tag:

> The HTML `<a>` element (or anchor element) creates a hyperlink to other
>   web pages, files, locations within the same page, email addresses, or
>   any other URL.

Am I missing something?

- Is this something that we accept like usage of `<i>` as an icon tag?
- Am I being too picky about the definition and *intended* usage of the
  tags?
- Is this something [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTML) doesn't care about since it's origin doesn't care about such usage?

I'm asking the question to understand the topic at a scholastic level.

Comment: I recommend you using <span> as its already an inline element which is really great for marking sections. But I am pretty sure someone will provide a better answer. So I am just putting a comment.

Comment: I was going to say <span></span> too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

Comment: The description for `<a>` given on MDN is, imho, incomplete at best and wrong at worst. If you read the [w3c standard page about `<a>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) it's a bit more nuanced than "it's an hyperlink".

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca — WHATWG and the W3C are different organisations (and really, that spec boils down to "It's a link or somewhere a link will be").

Comment: "Is this something that we accept like usage of `<i>` as an icon tag?" — "We" don't accept that, it's a terrible abuse of `<i>`. Use `<span>`.

Comment: @quentin, oops, wrong link. Still, the w3c description is the same, word for word.

Comment: @Quentin, I agree that it's a terrible abuse as well. But it seems to have become the terrible abuse that won't be undone anytime soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span>` is what you need.

**Two types of tags in HTML**

- **Semantic** clearly defines its contents and has specific rules and roles. `<ul> -> <li>` or `p` or `a`
- **Non-Semantic** Totally tells nothing about its content and they don't have any rules or roles. Example: `<span>` or `<div>`

HTML is for machines, not for humans to understand. So we should split tags into two parts. One for machines to understand and give specific roles (semantic) and one for us to provide not important contents (non-semantic).

When browser parses an `<a>` tag, it creates a special role for it. It is designed for navigation. And also search engines, screen readers try to use them for navigation. When search engine parses `<h1>`, it understands that this may be the title of the page and give more importance to it.

But non-semantic tags are totally unimportant for the machines. They don't have a specific role except for holding some content.

So we should be using non semantic tags to mark special contents for us. Maybe we will use selectors or styles, it is up to us.

**Why you shouldn't use div?**

`<div>` is a block element which wants to contain line.
`<span>` is an inline element.

`<span>` is totally non-semantic and has no meaning except for creating special contents with different styles or using with special types of functions like your case.

But the important thing here is understanding what semantic and non-semantic tags are.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no element with appropriate semantics (and `<a>` doesn't for this) then `<div>` and `<span>` are the generic fallback elements. `<span>` is inline, so use that.

Answer (score 0):

As [Ahmet Can Güven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836048/ahmet-can-g%C3%BCven) suggested and [Andrew Lohr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309377/andrew-lohr) agreed with in the comments to the question, [`<span>`  tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) seems to be the best tag to achieve the goal, as:

> `<span>` is very much like a  element, but  is a block-level
>   element whereas a `<span>` is an inline element.

and is:

> generic inline container for phrasing content, which does not
>   inherently represent anything.

```js
function updatePrice() {
  var current = Number($(".price").text());
  $(".price").text(1 + current);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>This item is $<span class="price">1</span></p>
<button onClick = "updatePrice();">One Up!</button>
```